# How to iterate async function in puppeteer with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I want to take a screenshot with puppeteer and it's working for one post. But I want to make it iterate.

If it's normal function I can just wrote the function name in the last side of the code so that it can iterate. But this is async function so I don't know how to iterate it.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let postNumber = 1;
let by;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\{computerName}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data',
        headless: false
    }); // default is true
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://band.us/band/{someNumbers}/post/${postNumber}`, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });
    let element = await page.$('.boardList');
    by = await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].textContent);
    console.log(by);

    await element.screenshot({
        path: `./image/${postNumber}-${by}.png`
    });
    console.log(`SAVED : ${postNumber}-${by}.png`)
    postNumber++;
    await browser.close();
})();
```

After the function is finished, the postNumber variable should be increase by one. And then run the code again by new URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any appropriate loop, like `while`-loop:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\{computerName}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data',
        headless: false
    }); // default is true
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    let postNumber = 1;
    while (postNumber <= 10) {
      await page.goto(`https://band.us/band/{someNumbers}/post/${postNumber}`, {
          waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
      });
      const element = await page.$('.boardList');
      const by = await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].textContent);
      console.log(by);

      await element.screenshot({
          path: `./image/${postNumber}-${by}.png`
      });
      console.log(`SAVED : ${postNumber}-${by}.png`)
      postNumber++;
    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

As you want to run the code one iteration after another, a normal for (or while) loop can be used. async/await code works fine with these.

You can use a for in your case like this:

```js
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/* ... */);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    for (let postNumber = 1; postNumber < 10; postNumber++) {
        await page.goto(/* ... */);
        let element = await page.$('.boardList');
        // ...
    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```